# MySQL: How to delete all rows where one column matches, but one is set to "-1"?

Tags: mysql, sql, linux

So say for instance I have:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| module      | module_id | document_no | status |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+
| demographic |        -1 |        1237 | A      |
| demographic |       475 |        1237 | A      |
+-------------+-----------+-------------+--------+
```

Imagine there are thousands of instances of document_no, where some have just a module_id of "-1" and some have module_id that isn't -1 as well as "-1". How could I remove all rows with a module_id of "-1" when it isn't the only module_id of that document_no?

Comment: `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the table with a subquery that returns all the document numbers that have another `module_id`.

```
DELETE t1
FROM yourTable AS t1
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT document_no
      FROM yourTable
      WHERE module_id != -1) AS t2
ON t1.document_no = t2.document_no
WHERE t1.module_id = -1
```